# multiple clients updating the same server model?

Tags: node.js, models

How can I send updates to a server model from all different clients and keep the changes to this model in order? How do I handle changes to the model being made at similar times?

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can attach a time-stamp to each update request, and the server would be responsible for keeping these updates in order.